# solr does not insert the first line in the csv file

Tags: csv, curl, solr, lucene

When a csv file is uploaded over curl command as below

```
C:\>curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?commit=true&stream.file=C:\dev\tools\solr-4.7.2\data.txt&stream.contentType=text/csv&header=false&fieldnames=id,cat,pubyear_i,title,author,
series_s,sequence_i&skipLines=0"
```

and data.txt content is as below

```
book1,fantasy,2000,A Storm of Swords,George R.R. Martin,A Song of Ice and Fire,3
book2,fantasy,2005,A Feast for Crows,George R.R. Martin,A Song of Ice and Fire,4
book3,fantasy,2011,A Dance with Dragons,George R.R. Martin,A Song of Ice and Fire,5
book4,sci-fi,1987,Consider Phlebas,Iain M. Banks,The Culture,1
book5,sci-fi,1988,The Player of Games,Iain M. Banks,The Culture,2
book6,sci-fi,1990,Use of Weapons,Iain M. Banks,The Culture,3
book7,fantasy,1984,Shadows Linger,Glen Cook,The Black Company,2
book8,fantasy,1984,The White Rose,Glen Cook,The Black Company,3
book9,fantasy,1989,Shadow Games,Glen Cook,The Black Company,4
book10,sci-fi,2001,Gridlinked,Neal Asher,Ian Cormac,1
book11,sci-fi,2003,The Line of Polity,Neal Asher,Ian Cormac,2
book12,sci-fi,2005,Brass Man,Neal Asher,Ian Cormac,3
```

first data in data.txt file is not being inserted to Solr which its id is "book1". Can someone please tell why?

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=id:book1
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:book1"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Solr logs already tells that book1 is being added.

```
15440876 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  û [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@177fcdf1[collection1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1g:124:nrt _z(4.7):C12)}
15440877 [qtp84034882-11] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  û [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={fieldnames=id,cat,pubyear_i,title,author,series_s,sequence_i&skipLines=0&commit=true&stream.con
tentType=text/csv&header=false&stream.file=C:\dev\tools\solr-4.7.2\data.txt} {add=[?book1 (1480070032327180288), book2 (1480070032332423168), book3 (1480070032335568896), book4 (1480070032337666048), book5 (1480070032339763200), b
ook6 (1480070032341860352), book7 (1480070032343957504), book8 (1480070032347103232), book9 (1480070032349200384), book10 (1480070032351297536), ... (12 adds)],commit=} 0 92
```

If I ask for all data then below you can also see book1 is still missing

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=id:book*&sort=pubyear_i+desc&fl=id,title,pubyear_i&rows=15
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "fl":"id,title,pubyear_i",
      "sort":"pubyear_i desc",
      "q":"id:book*",
      "rows":"15"}},
  "response":{"numFound":11,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"book3",
        "pubyear_i":2011,
        "title":["A Dance with Dragons"]},
      {
        "id":"book2",
        "pubyear_i":2005,
        "title":["A Feast for Crows"]},
      {
        "id":"book12",
        "pubyear_i":2005,
        "title":["Brass Man"]},
      {
        "id":"book11",
        "pubyear_i":2003,
        "title":["The Line of Polity"]},
      {
        "id":"book10",
        "pubyear_i":2001,
        "title":["Gridlinked"]},
      {
        "id":"book6",
        "pubyear_i":1990,
        "title":["Use of Weapons"]},
      {
        "id":"book9",
        "pubyear_i":1989,
        "title":["Shadow Games"]},
      {
        "id":"book5",
        "pubyear_i":1988,
        "title":["The Player of Games"]},
      {
        "id":"book4",
        "pubyear_i":1987,
        "title":["Consider Phlebas"]},
      {
        "id":"book7",
        "pubyear_i":1984,
        "title":["Shadows Linger"]},
      {
        "id":"book8",
        "pubyear_i":1984,
        "title":["The White Rose"]}]
  }}
```

data.txt context by hex data

```
0000000 ef bb bf 62 6f 6f 6b 31 2c 66 61 6e 74 61 73 79
0000020 2c 32 30 30 30 2c 41 20 53 74 6f 72 6d 20 6f 66
0000040 20 53 77 6f 72 64 73 2c 47 65 6f 72 67 65 20 52
0000060 2e 52 2e 20 4d 61 72 74 69 6e 2c 41 20 53 6f 6e
0000100 67 20 6f 66 20 49 63 65 20 61 6e 64 20 46 69 72
0000120 65 2c 33 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b 32 2c 66 61 6e 74 61
0000140 73 79 2c 32 30 30 35 2c 41 20 46 65 61 73 74 20
0000160 66 6f 72 20 43 72 6f 77 73 2c 47 65 6f 72 67 65
0000200 20 52 2e 52 2e 20 4d 61 72 74 69 6e 2c 41 20 53
0000220 6f 6e 67 20 6f 66 20 49 63 65 20 61 6e 64 20 46
0000240 69 72 65 2c 34 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b 33 2c 66 61 6e
0000260 74 61 73 79 2c 32 30 31 31 2c 41 20 44 61 6e 63
0000300 65 20 77 69 74 68 20 44 72 61 67 6f 6e 73 2c 47
0000320 65 6f 72 67 65 20 52 2e 52 2e 20 4d 61 72 74 69
0000340 6e 2c 41 20 53 6f 6e 67 20 6f 66 20 49 63 65 20
0000360 61 6e 64 20 46 69 72 65 2c 35 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b
0000400 34 2c 73 63 69 2d 66 69 2c 31 39 38 37 2c 43 6f
0000420 6e 73 69 64 65 72 20 50 68 6c 65 62 61 73 2c 49
0000440 61 69 6e 20 4d 2e 20 42 61 6e 6b 73 2c 54 68 65
0000460 20 43 75 6c 74 75 72 65 2c 31 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b
0000500 35 2c 73 63 69 2d 66 69 2c 31 39 38 38 2c 54 68
0000520 65 20 50 6c 61 79 65 72 20 6f 66 20 47 61 6d 65
0000540 73 2c 49 61 69 6e 20 4d 2e 20 42 61 6e 6b 73 2c
0000560 54 68 65 20 43 75 6c 74 75 72 65 2c 32 0d 0a 62
0000600 6f 6f 6b 36 2c 73 63 69 2d 66 69 2c 31 39 39 30
0000620 2c 55 73 65 20 6f 66 20 57 65 61 70 6f 6e 73 2c
0000640 49 61 69 6e 20 4d 2e 20 42 61 6e 6b 73 2c 54 68
0000660 65 20 43 75 6c 74 75 72 65 2c 33 0d 0a 62 6f 6f
0000700 6b 37 2c 66 61 6e 74 61 73 79 2c 31 39 38 34 2c
0000720 53 68 61 64 6f 77 73 20 4c 69 6e 67 65 72 2c 47
0000740 6c 65 6e 20 43 6f 6f 6b 2c 54 68 65 20 42 6c 61
0000760 63 6b 20 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 2c 32 0d 0a 62 6f
0001000 6f 6b 38 2c 66 61 6e 74 61 73 79 2c 31 39 38 34
0001020 2c 54 68 65 20 57 68 69 74 65 20 52 6f 73 65 2c
0001040 47 6c 65 6e 20 43 6f 6f 6b 2c 54 68 65 20 42 6c
0001060 61 63 6b 20 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 2c 33 0d 0a 62
0001100 6f 6f 6b 39 2c 66 61 6e 74 61 73 79 2c 31 39 38
0001120 39 2c 53 68 61 64 6f 77 20 47 61 6d 65 73 2c 47
0001140 6c 65 6e 20 43 6f 6f 6b 2c 54 68 65 20 42 6c 61
0001160 63 6b 20 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 2c 34 0d 0a 62 6f
0001200 6f 6b 31 30 2c 73 63 69 2d 66 69 2c 32 30 30 31
0001220 2c 47 72 69 64 6c 69 6e 6b 65 64 2c 4e 65 61 6c
0001240 20 41 73 68 65 72 2c 49 61 6e 20 43 6f 72 6d 61
0001260 63 2c 31 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b 31 31 2c 73 63 69 2d
0001300 66 69 2c 32 30 30 33 2c 54 68 65 20 4c 69 6e 65
0001320 20 6f 66 20 50 6f 6c 69 74 79 2c 4e 65 61 6c 20
0001340 41 73 68 65 72 2c 49 61 6e 20 43 6f 72 6d 61 63
0001360 2c 32 0d 0a 62 6f 6f 6b 31 32 2c 73 63 69 2d 66
0001400 69 2c 32 30 30 35 2c 42 72 61 73 73 20 4d 61 6e
0001420 2c 4e 65 61 6c 20 41 73 68 65 72 2c 49 61 6e 20
0001440 43 6f 72 6d 61 63 2c 33 0d 0a
0001452
```

Comment: does it contains everything else?

Comment: yes except 'book1' in the first line it contains everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at the log... it says that "?book1" was added (notice the question mark in the ID).
My best guess is that there are some funny characters at the start of the file that become part of the ID.  Perhaps a BOM (I know some text editors annoyingly add that).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

You could verify something is there by using "hexdump data.txt" or "od -tx1 data.txt"
You could also try a different text editor that would allow you to delete that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first line gets treated as a header.

But you do have header parameter. I would check it is spelt correctly, maybe move it earlier in the parameter list. Check that solrconfig.xml does not override that value.

Also, if you are using Solr 4+, try skipping the /csv bit at the end of the URL. It's a legacy address and maybe it has some expectations about the header line.

Comment: yeap it is being spelled correctly and even if i remove /csv it still does not insert "book1". I am using 4+ also. What do you mean by solrconfig.xml i mean which parameter should i check for. i added solr logs to my question.

Comment: <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="stream.contentType">application/csv</str>
       </lst>
  </requestHandler>

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Can you just try the same in your solr and get the same result.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you actually using?

Comment: 4.7.2 solr i am using